# Low drop out regulator

Tags: ldo

For an LDO (Low drop-out regulator) I am having below two questions but couldnt find a good reference to answer them.

1. What determines Bandwidth of an LDO? For e.g. for a change in load current what range of frequencies can be supported by an LDO to maintain constant output voltage. Any mathematical equation to answer this?
2. What decides the maximum load current for which an LDO can regulate the output voltage?
   [image]

Comment: These are complicated questions and you need to open the transistor-level schematic of a linear regulator to look at the small-signal output impedance, open-loop gain and protection circuitry. I remember writing an [article](https://www.edn.com/get-the-best-from-your-low-dropout-regulator/) on LDOs some years ago if it can help.

Comment: They invented something, it's called datasheet, MCP1792, 250 mA Low Quiescent Current LDO Regulator: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22008E.pdf, has a lot of graphical plots, your answers is probably there, professional engineers broke their head on a schematic for it and it's used for micro controllers. no need to build one yourself. the datasheet also shows a circuit.